Inverse discrete Lyapunov equation: given positive-definite $P > Q > 0$, what is $A$ when $A^TPA - P = -Q$
I'm very interested in how to characterize solutions to the inverse discrete-time Lyapunov equation. Let $P>Q>0$ be positive-definite matrices. Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote all solutions to the discrete-time Lyapunov equation $A^TPA - P = -Q$. How can we characterize the set $\mathcal{A}$?

If $A_0$ is a single solution to the DT Lyapunov equation, then for any orthogonal matrix $U$, the matrix $A = P^{-1/2}UA_0$ is another solution to the equation. I suspect that (given one solution $A_0$) all elements of $\mathcal A$ can be obtained in this fashion.

That's interesting. I wonder, as well.

It’s equivalent to $(P-Q)^{-1/2}A^TPA(P-Q)^{-1/2}=I$, i.e., $P^{1/2}A(P-Q)^{-1/2}$ is an orthogonal matrix. Hence the general solution is given by $A=P^{-1/2}U(P-Q)^{1/2}$ where $U\in O(n)$ is arbitrary.

For a (symmetric) positive definite matrix $M$, I use $M^{1/2}$ to denote the unique
Note that the equation can be rewritten as follows.
$$
A^TPA = P - Q\\
A^TP^{1/2}P^{1/2}A = [(P-Q)^{1/2}]^2\\
(P-Q)^{-1/2}A^TP^{1/2}P^{1/2}A(P-Q)^{-1/2} = I\\
[P^{1/2}A(P-Q)^{-1/2}]^T[P^{1/2}A(P-Q)^{-1/2}] = I
$$
In other words, $A$ satisfies the equation if an only if $P^{1/2}A(P-Q)^{-1/2}$ is an orthogonal matrix. In other words, $A$ satisfies the system if and only if there is an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that
$$
P^{1/2}A(P-Q)^{-1/2} = U \iff A = P^{-1/2}U(P-Q)^{1/2}.
$$
That is, every solution has the form $A = P^{-1/2}U(P-Q)^{1/2}$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$.
